# Symfony project shows directory index instead of index page

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I am new to Symfony, and I've just created a new project on a Debian server. The folder is /var/www/symfony. I've use the instructions as defined here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

When I access that folder from my web browser, I see the directory index with files. But I'm missing the default page.

I've checked the following:

1. Permissions have been configured as read/write for the web server
   user/group/
2. The Directory in Apache2 has been configured as
   AllowOverrride All
3. The DefaultController.php file has a "/" route defined.

When I try to run the PHP internal web server from the project directory (php bin/console server:run):

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /var/www/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php on line 386
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/symfony/bin/console:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug::enable() /var/www/symfony/bin/console:24
PHP   3. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() /var/www/symfony/bin/console:0
PHP   4. Composer\Autoload\includeFile() /var/www/symfony/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:301
```

I'm running PHP 5.4.54. Is this a bug in Symfony, or am I missing something?

Comment: Is `AllowOverrride` a typo in the question or your vhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony 3.0 and above requires you to use PHP 5.5.9 or higher.

Comment: Apparently that was the case. After upgrading PHP, I could access the web page by browsing to /web

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your DocumentRoot is pointing to **/var/www/symfonyproject/web** folder in apache configuration file. Please see below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.tld
    ServerAlias www.domain.tld

    DocumentRoot /var/www/project/web
    <Directory /var/www/project/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost
```